# Вывод имен из списка по условию

Tags: python, list

Не могу понять, в чём ошибка.

Задание: Дан список имен: `[‘Rose’, ‘Nina’, ‘Phillip’, ‘Alex’, ‘Jimmy’, ‘Max’]`. Вывести на экран приветственную строку в формате ‘Hello name’ для всех имен длиной не более 4-х символов. При этом все имена, следующие за именем, содержащим букву ‘x’, должны быть проигнорированы.

```
list = ['Rose', 'Nina', 'Phillip', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Max']
for i in list:
    if len(i) > 4:
        continue
    for n in range(1, len(i)):
        if i[n] == 'x':
           break
    print(i)
```

```
Rose
Nina
Alex
Max
```

это вывод, а должно быть без Alex,Max

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Там "все имена, следующие за именем , содержащим "x", должны игнорироваться? Т.е. после того как встретили имя со вхождением "x" прекращаем?

```
import re

list = ['Rose', 'Nina', 'Phillip', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Max']
for i in list:
    if re.search(r'[xX]', i) != None:
        break
    if len(i) > 4:
        continue

    print(i)
```

Comment: спасибо, Дмитрий

Comment: ну не знаю, мне -2 в карму за этот ответ влетело, так что смотрите сами. ИМХО в задаче надо прекращать вывод, встретив имя с "х" не зависимо от регистра, потому и регулярку вставил вперед условия про длину (у нас может быть имя с "х" длиннее 4 символов и надо прекращать вывод, если я правильно понял задачу)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять в чем ошибка, взглянем на Ваш код:

```
for n in range(1, len(i)):
        if i[n] == 'x':
           break
```

В коде выше у вас выход из цикла происходит из внутреннего, то есть чтобы дальше не было вывода имен с символом 'x', необходимо выйти из внешнего цикла `for`

Вот мое решение:

```py
list_names = ['Rose', 'Nina', 'Phillip', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Max']
flag = False
for name in list_names:
    if len(name) > 4:
       continue
    if flag:
        break
    if "x" in name:
        flag = True
    print("Hello,", name)
```

Флаг `flag` здесь используется чтобы найти первое имя с символом 'x', и проверка, найден ли такой ранее.
Вывод такой:

```
Hello, Rose
Hello, Nina
Hello, Alex
```

Alex в данном случае включен в вывод, потому что игнорируются только имена, которые следуют после имени со символом 'x'

Comment: Спасибо, Ovsenka

Answer (score 1):

Break прерывает только один цикл, в котором он находится. Можно сделать сложно на try except, чтобы прервать несколько вложенных циклов. Но проще воспользоваться существующей в python кoнструкцией `el in str`

```
list = ['Rose', 'Nina', 'Phillip', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Max']
for i in list:
    if len(i) > 4:
       continue
    if 'x' in i:
        break
    print(i)
```

Comment: Разве Alex не должен выводить?

Comment: кто ж его знает, скажет автор вопроса, что надо - поправим

Comment: Спасибо , за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['Rose', 'Nina', 'Phillip', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Max']

for name in list:
    if len(name) < 5:
        if 'x' in name:
            print("Hello,", name)
            break
        else:
            print("Hello,", name)
```

Вывод:

```
Hello, Rose
Hello, Nina
Hello, Alex
```

Comment: спасибо, Mango )